# Hide ToolbarAndroid while scrolling listview

Tags: react-native

I am using [React Native ToolbarAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html#content).

**It is possible to hide it smoothly while scrolling ListView like [HERE](https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/800/1*WGo-RCf8RzLztOFBGTEe0g.gif)?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this could be the answer...

https://github.com/cesardeazevedo/react-native-collapsing-toolbar